# Filtrar Array de Objetos en base a un atributo en comun

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de filtrar de mayor a menor un Array de objetos en base a una propiedad en comun que es el precio hasta aca mi codigo,

```js
class Vehiculos {
            constructor(marca,modelo,puertas,cilindrada, precio){
                this.marca = marca;
                this.modelo = modelo;
                this.puertas = puertas;
                this.cilindrada = cilindrada;
                this.precio = precio;
            }          
            
        }
        

        let vehiculo1 = new Vehiculos();
            vehiculo1.marca = "Peugeot";
            vehiculo1.modelo = "206";
            vehiculo1.puertas = 4;
            vehiculo1.precio = 200000;

        let vehiculo2 = new Vehiculos();
            vehiculo2.marca = "Honda";
            vehiculo2.modelo = "Titan";
            vehiculo2.cilindrada = "125c";
            vehiculo2.precio = 60000;

        let vehiculo3 = new Vehiculos();
            vehiculo3.marca = "Peugeot";
            vehiculo3.modelo = "208";
            vehiculo3.puertas = 5;
            vehiculo3.precio = 250000;

        let vehiculo4 = new Vehiculos();
            vehiculo4.marca = "Yamaha";
            vehiculo4.modelo = "YBR";
            vehiculo4.cilindrada = "160c";
            vehiculo4.precio = 80500.50;

        var vehiculos = [vehiculo1,vehiculo2,vehiculo3,vehiculo4];
        
   let mayorAMenor = vehiculos.filter(vehiculo => {
            
            return vehiculo.precio <= 250000 && vehiculo.precio >= 60000;
         })
          
          console.log(mayorAMenor);
```

lo que se me complica debe ser la operacion logica en el filter, quizas deberia obtener el maximo y  el minimo con Math.max() y Math.min() y luego evaluar mejor con el filter.

Saludos!

Comment: Si estás usando clases, deberías tener métodos como setMarca, porque la idea concreta de las clases, es no poder acceder directamente a las propiedades, sino, utilizar funciones que se encarguen de ello. Es una muy mala práctica.

Comment: Filtrar != Ordenar

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la funcion `Array.sort( funcionOrden )` para ordenar items de un array.

La funcion `funcionOrden(a,b)` recibe como argumentos 2 elementos. Retornas 1 para indicar que es mayor, -1 para indicar que es menor y 0 para indicar que son iguales.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort

```js
class Vehiculos {
            constructor(marca,modelo,puertas,cilindrada, precio){
                this.marca = marca;
                this.modelo = modelo;
                this.puertas = puertas;
                this.cilindrada = cilindrada;
                this.precio = precio;
            }          
            
        }
        

        let vehiculo1 = new Vehiculos();
            vehiculo1.marca = "Peugeot";
            vehiculo1.modelo = "206";
            vehiculo1.puertas = 4;
            vehiculo1.precio = 200000;

        let vehiculo2 = new Vehiculos();
            vehiculo2.marca = "Honda";
            vehiculo2.modelo = "Titan";
            vehiculo2.cilindrada = "125c";
            vehiculo2.precio = 60000;

        let vehiculo3 = new Vehiculos();
            vehiculo3.marca = "Peugeot";
            vehiculo3.modelo = "208";
            vehiculo3.puertas = 5;
            vehiculo3.precio = 250000;

        let vehiculo4 = new Vehiculos();
            vehiculo4.marca = "Yamaha";
            vehiculo4.modelo = "YBR";
            vehiculo4.cilindrada = "160c";
            vehiculo4.precio = 80500.50;

        var vehiculos = [vehiculo1,vehiculo2,vehiculo3,vehiculo4];
        
   let mayorAMenor = vehiculos.sort(function(a,b){
            
            return (a.precio < b.precio ? 1 : (a.precio > b.precio ? -1 : 0 ));
         })
          
          console.log(mayorAMenor);
```